Density function of the sum of 2 random variables
I am trying to follow a proof for the formula of the density function of the sum of 2 random variables (continuous case). The proposition is as follows:

Let $(X,Y)$ be a continuous vector with a joint density function $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$. Then $X+Y$ has a density function
$$
f_{X+Y}(u) =  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{X,Y}(u-v,v) dv \
$$

Note that the formula is for a general case, meaning, we do not know yet if the random variables are independent. If they are, it is within my understanding that we would be entering the topic of convolution.
In the book that I am following the demonstration, they claim that $ f_{X+Y,Y}(u,v)=f_{X,Y}(u-v,v) $. This seemingly obvious fact is what I am having trouble understanding. I fail to see clearly how this has come to be. If anyone could explain it to me or share any resources that might be useful for me I would appreciate it. Thank you.

using the change of variables $U = X+Y$ and $V = Y$ you get $x =u-v$ and $y = v$. Then $f_{U,V}(u,v) = f_{X,Y}(u-v,v)$

In case you are not up on Jacobian transformations, you could consider the joint cdf for $X+Y$ and $Y$.
$$
F_{X+Y,Y}(u,v) = P(X+Y \leq u, Y \leq v)
$$
You can compute this by integrating over the appropriate region as shown here.

So
$$
F_{X+Y,Y}(u,v) = \int_{-\infty}^{v} \int_{-\infty}^{u-y} f_{X,Y} (x,y) \, dx \, dy.
$$
Now find the joint pdf for $X+Y$ and $Y$ by taking derivatives and using the fundamental theorem of calculus:
$$
\begin{array}{lcl}
f_{X+Y,Y}(u,v) &=& \frac{d}{dv} \frac{d}{du} \int_{-\infty}^{v} \int_{-\infty}^{u-y} f_{X,Y} (x,y) \, dx \, dy\\[1em]
&=& \frac{d}{dv}  \int_{-\infty}^{v} \frac{d}{du} \int_{-\infty}^{u-y} f_{X,Y} (x,y) \, dx \, dy\\[1em]
&=& \frac{d}{dv}  \int_{-\infty}^{v}  f_{X,Y} (u-y,y)  \, dy\\[1em]
&=& f_{X,Y}(u-v,v)
\end{array}
$$

Thank you! This is really helpful for understanding it better.
